# why do we need to setup a publish address[network.host] value

Tags: elasticsearch, ip-address, distributed

Looks like elastic search is not discoverable without setting the box's ip address in this property : **network.host** .

Why cant it just bind to the box's ip address(like it happens in application servers like rest apps). 
Why is there even a provision to bind to a particular ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key property that matters is `network.publish_host`. You configure this indirectly via `network.host`. The publish host is the address that nodes advertise to other nodes as the address to be reached on when they join the cluster. So, it needs to be something that is reachable from the other nodes. E.g. 127.0.0.1 would not work for this; likewise a loadbalanced address won't work either.

Also see [documentation for these properties](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html)

Many servers have multiple network interfaces and a common problem before this change was Elasticsearch picking the wrong one for the publish host and then failing to cluster because the nodes ended up advertising the wrong address to each other. Since Elasticsearch cannot know the right interface, you have to tell it.

Answer (score 1):

This change has been introduced in 2.0 as explained in the [breaking changes > network changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html) documentation:

> This change prevents Elasticsearch from trying to connect to other nodes on your network unless you specifically tell it to do so. When moving to production you should configure the network.host parameter

The ES folks also released a [blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-unplugged) back then to explain the underlying reasons for this change, i.e. mainly to prevent your node from accidentally binding to another cluster available on the network.

Comment: Even if somebody does put the box's proper ip address in network.host , it would connect to the elastic search network on that network. The same would have happened if localhost resolves to that ip. How does it prevent the accidental binding?   Could you check my question again..

Answer (score 0):

To run on a local network a single node I added these to my 
un-comment or comment 
elasticsearch.yml

```
http.port: 9201
http.bind_host: 192.168.1.172 #works
```

or

```
http.port: 9201
http.publish_host: 192.168.1.172 #by itself does not work
http.host: 192.168.1.172 #works alone
```